# customize \section on odd and even pages

Tags: book-design

I'm using the code fragment shown below, where I have a specific shape for each section, but it has a problem in the two-side mode.

How should I solve the problem?

Thanks for your help.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}‎

‎\usepackage[a4paper‎, ‎width=13cm‎, ‎left=1cm]{geometry}‎
‎\usepackage{graphicx}‎
‎\usepackage{titlesec}‎
‎\usepackage{lastpage}‎
‎\usepackage{tikz}‎
‎\usepackage{lipsum}‎

‎\usepackage{makeidx}‎
‎\makeindex‎
‎\usepackage[pagebackref=false]{hyperref}‎

‎\makeatletter‎

‎\makeatother‎ 
‎\titleformat{\section}[display]‎
‎{\normalfont\color{black}}‎ 
‎{\filleft\large‎
‎\vspace*{1ex}‎
‎$\begin{tikzpicture}‎
‎\draw node(a) (8,0) [xshift=8.1cm,inner sep=12pt,draw] {\thesection};‎
‎\draw (a.east)(8.8,0)‎ -- ‎(11,0) ;‎
‎\draw (a.east)(8.8,-0.3)‎ -- ‎(11,-0.3) ;‎
‎\draw (a.east)(8.8,0.4)‎ -- ‎(11,0.4) ;‎
‎\draw (a.east)(8.8,0.2)‎ -- ‎(11,0.2) ;‎
‎\draw (a.west)(-7,-0.3)‎ -- ‎(7.3,-0.3);‎
‎\end{tikzpicture}$‎
}
‎{-10ex}‎
‎{\filleft \large\bfseries}‎ []
‎\titleformat{name=\numberless}[display]‎
‎{\normalfont\color{black}}‎ {} 
‎%{0.5ex}‎
‎{\vspace*{3ex}\huge}‎ []

‎\begin{document}‎
‎\pagenumbering{arabic}‎
‎\chapter{chapter}‎
‎\lipsum‎
‎\section{section}‎
‎\lipsum‎
‎\section{section}‎
‎\end{document}
```

This results in the following:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the problem exactly? Could you clarify your question?

Comment: that's the problem that is two-side on the even page the shape is not in the right place.

Comment: Are you sure that your code gives the correct output on odd pages? There are errors in the tikzpicture.

Comment: yes i sure.
I put a picture of it

Comment: But the code you posted does not produce the output on this picture. The code cannot even be compiled since there are errors in the tikzpicture.

Comment: !!!!    It's weird really !!! :((
But I  got the same code and sent the photo